# Looking for an old (probably 1980's) anime movie. Futuristic machine-god named Kali

Tags: story-identification, anime

I watched this on VHS when I was like 8 years old and it definitely wasn't suitable for someone that age.

The story was about a planet where people like humans lived, BUT there was a religious cult with goddess Kali, which was actually a machine and turned humanity into machines via little spiders inserting their heads. They slowly took over the whole kingdom.

At the same time, there were two siblings (that didn't know they were siblings) and their power combined was the only chance humanity had.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  We don't know when you were 8; approximately what year was that?  Can you describe the age and appearance of the sibilings?  Children, teens, same-coloured hair or different...

Comment: Not what you're after, but comes up as a solid match :-) https://www.the7thmatrix.com/blog/category/Cyberpunk

Comment: Hello, 

you are right, i was 8 in 1991, i think this is an 80s anime movie though, like i wrote in the title.

The sibling were grown up, like 20 years old each. I dont remember any characteristics sadly, i do remember that they didnt know they were siblings from the start and that the girl could not control her powers at the start. 

Her (and his) powers when used solo, could like blow up a tank, but combined, they could whipe out like 30 of them.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm almost sure it is [*Andromeda Lost Galaxy*](https://www.cartonionline.com/en/characters/andromeda_galaxy_perduta.htm), an 80s anime movie

I watched it a long time ago (and I found it very scary, too,) so I don't remember the plot perfectly, but I remember some pieces, like the two sibilings as protagonists and the machines (spiders, but also some kind of bats) entering the heads of human beings and taking control of them.
One of the main characters was a kind of samurai-girl, who tried to help the two sibilings, if rings any bells.

From the linked site:

> Andromeda Lost Galaxy (Hepburn: Andoromeda Sutorizu in the Japanese original) is an animated film based on the manga comic written by Ryu Mitsuse and drawn by Keiko Takemiya. The anime was produced in 1982 by Toei Animation and aired for the first time by the Japanese network Nippon Television on August 22, 1982.

> The story tells of when on the planet Astria in the Andromeda Galaxy, Prince Ithaca marries Princess Lilia of Ayodoya, crowning him king of Astralta III. Unfortunately, the honeymoon of the happy couple is cut short, when monstrous machines from another planet invade Astria, with the intention of controlling the minds of humans and terraforming the fertile and green planet, in a desert inhabited only by forms of mechanical and artificial life. After the king and his ministers are assimilated by the alien machines, Queen Lilia and her newborn son, Prince Jimsa, must flee Astria. However the natives of Astria are unaware that the exiles from the planet Murat (the source of the enemy) have actually selectively bred the royal lines and Prince Jimsa is the final fruit of their efforts. It is intended to lead their resistance against alien machines.

Comment: You're a GOD. YES! this is it! Thanks a lot, I was looking for it for ages!

Comment: @ChristopherKourouzidis Please accept this answer by clicking on the checkmark in the upper left beneath the voting arrows.

Comment: Any mention of Kali?

Comment: @ChristopherKourouzidis I am guessing you're Greek from the name, so I just want to point out that "you're a God" doesn't work in English. If you want a translation of the Greek "είσαι θεός", go for "you're a legend". :)